# Why is my database losing changes when I kill the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm implementing a persistent card game to learn Core Data and MagicalRecord and I'm experiencing a strange issue when I change the order of the cards in the deck. The cards are implemented as an NSOrderedSet so that I can persist the order of the cards in the deck. When I change the order of any two cards, they appear to be persisted when I display them on the screen. However, if I kill the app and display the cards, the changes to the order of the cards are lost.  Here's my simple code for swapping two cards and saving the changes...

```
MyDeck *deck = [MyDeck MR_findFirstInContext:managedObjectContext]; 
[deck.CardsSet exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex withObjectAtIndex:toIndex];
[managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Do you see any reason why these changes would get lost after the app is killed?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Would it not be easier to add an index field and sort on that?

Comment: @amergin, I'm trying to understand why this approach is not working.

Comment: I don't think core data stores stuff as an NSOrderedSet (just as NSSets) so just cos you use them in your app as an ordered set doesn't mean when you read them back in they'll be ordered. Just my 2c

Comment: @amergin, allow me to answer your question for you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750326/how-can-i-preserve-an-ordered-list-in-core-data

Comment: Mea culpa - must be my age weakened memory. Have you found the solution to this yourself yet?