# Sort data entries in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

When I'm using CoreData database, I realize that the data is not store in order. For example, if I store "Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3", "Project 4", and then fetch them back in the view controller, the order I'm getting is `2, 3, 4, 1`. It turns out to be annoying since the display of these data is messed up. How do I sort the data so that they could come out in order?

Comment: Is this not related / answered here: (preserve an ordered list in core data)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750326/how-can-i-preserve-an-ordered-list-in-core-data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a fetch using NSSortDescriptor.

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CaseType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"caseType" ascending:YES];
 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

 NSPredicate *activePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active == 1"];
 [fetchRequest activePred];

 NSError *error;
 NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use NSSortDescriptor

apple has good documentation for this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html